# Hyperledger Fabric : How to Query blocks using fabric NodeSDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been going through FabCar sample from hyperledger official site below are my questions.

1. What is the purpose of transaction ID that were generated which we get as a response after successfully making a transaction?
2. Does that **transactionID** be helpful in querying particular block?
3. Is it the right way to **query CouchDB** and get results? or do the blocks needs to be **explored/queried**, if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use transaction ID to retrieve that specific processed transaction, using

[`channel.queryTransaction(tx_id, target, useAdmin, skipDecode)`](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.3/Channel.html#queryTransaction) 
which returns a promise for a fully decoded [ProcessedTransaction](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.3/global.html#ProcessedTransaction) object.

The processed transaction will contain all the information you need about the transaction including the block number, which you can then use to fetch the appropriate block using

[`channel.queryBlock(blockNumber, target, useAdmin, skipDecode)`](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.3/Channel.html#queryBlock)

Comment: thanks much for the response @ClydeD'Cruz that could really be helpful.
Will go through the above and query my blocks.

Comment: Your'e welcome. If it solves your problem, you can mark the answer as accepted. :)  https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: Hi @Clyde D'Cruz, May I ask another question ? ;)