# Hyperledger Fabric Version 2: How to query Block Header such as data hash, previous hash by using Fabric Node SDK 2.2

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to build a decentralized app that able to do show the block header like data hash, the previous hash of the block when a user submits a new transaction. However, It seems like the new version of **Fabric Node SDK 2.2** removes the function queryblock.

I refer on the documentation at https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/module-fabric-network.html and currently still looking for some workaround to show the block info of the user's transaction.

The ideal output that I wish to achieved is almost similar to what Hyperledger Explorer provide.The reference can be check at:

- https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer

which show the information such as Number of Blocks, Data Hash, Previous Hash and other Block Information regarding the hash.

## Some information that I able to gather

1. There are some information like BlockEvent that have the name `blockData` in the interface `BlockEvent`. However, I can't seem to find it when `npm install i fabric-network`.

   - https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/module-fabric-network.BlockEvent.html
2. Since the user can query and check their hash with the ledger, a **key or hash** need to be returned to the user upon transaction success. Is there any API function for this? So far, I able to found there are `getTransactionId()` in the class `Transaction`. But is this one that I need to use?

   - https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/module-fabric-network.Transaction.html

## StackOverflow reference that I had gone over:

All of the reference since to deal with the old version of node SDK which is version 1.4.

- [Hyperledger Fabric : How to Query blocks using fabric NodeSDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53338276/hyperledger-fabric-how-to-query-blocks-using-fabric-nodesdk)
- [HyperLedger Fabric Get Block Info - using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62043779/hyperledger-fabric-get-block-info-using-node-js)
- [how to display current hash,previous hash using node js on view pages for hyperledger fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671262/how-to-display-current-hash-previous-hash-using-node-js-on-view-pages-for-hyperl)
- [How do you calculate the Block Hash for the Current Block in Hyperledger Fabric with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595061/how-do-you-calculate-the-block-hash-for-the-current-block-in-hyperledger-fabric?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How to get history of asset with block hash in hyperledger fabric using node sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64597558/how-to-get-history-of-asset-with-block-hash-in-hyperledger-fabric-using-node-sdk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query block number by call function `GetBlockByNumber` of `qscc` contract. Example:

```js
const contract = network.getContract('qscc');
const resultByte = await contract.evaluateTransaction(
    'GetBlockByNumber',
    channelName,
    String(blockNum)
);
const resultJson = BlockDecoder.decode(resultByte);
logger.debug('queryBlock', resultJson);
```